# disclosing firebase apiKey

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Documentation of firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup tell us we can safely expose firebase apiKey:

> **Note:** The Firebase config object contains unique, but non-secret
>   identifiers for your Firebase project.

The tutorial explains how to obtain the apiKey and insert it into the HTML code of our web app. Everyone can read that key. I would understand this is only an identification key.

But recently I received this message from google:

> We have detected a publicly accessible Google API key associated with
>   the following Google Cloud Platform project:
>
> [...]
>
> The key was found at the following URL:
>
> [...]
>
> We believe that you or your organization may have inadvertently
>   published the affected API key in public sources or on public websites
>   (for example, credentials mistakenly uploaded to a service such as
>   GitHub.)
>
> Please note that as the project/account owner, you are responsible for
>   securing your keys. Therefore, we recommend that you take the
>   following steps to remedy this situation:
>
> 1. If this key is intended to be public (or if a publicly accessible
>      key isn’t preventable):
>          Log in to the Google Cloud Console and review the API and
>      billing activity on your account, ensuring the usage is in line with
>      what you expected.
>          Add API key restrictions to your API key, if applicable.
> 2. If this key was NOT meant to be public:
>          Regenerate the compromised API key: Search for Credentials in
>      the cloud console platform, Edit the leaked key, and use the
>      Regenerate Key button to rotate the key. For more details, review the
>      instructions on handling compromised GCP credentials.
>          Take immediate steps to ensure that your API key(s) are not embedded in public source code systems, stored in download
>      directories, or unintentionally shared in other ways.
>          Add API key restrictions to your API key, if applicable.

In general I would say that the two sources of information are in contrast each-other. Is it true that the apiKey is "non-secret"? Reading also the related question [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public) I'm not really sure. I understand that the apiKey is enough to access the whole database if rules allow to.

First question: I wonder if I can be assured that the apiKey only gives access to the database (which can be restricted by rules) or if it gives also access to other information about the project. What about storage? The user can read files? Can write them? The key is called "web API key" so I understand is a unique identifier of the project. Before receiving the message from google I have considered it more as an identifier than a key. Since every access to the project API is a potential cost for me, the owner of the project, I understand that a key is required for billing purposes.

Second question. Since I would like to have full control of what user can access in the database my application is presenting a REST api as an interface to the database (using functions). So the user is not supposed to directly access the database. I have the following rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /global/public {
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

The intention is that user can only read the documents prefixed with /global/public (currently empty). So I think the database is secured. Now I wonder if I really need to expose the apiKey... Is the apiKey required for user authentication? If so, can I ignore the message from google and leave the apiKey public?
​

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Am I not supposed to include the google-services.json file on the apk?